# How to implement running of coupling constants in condensed matter

Tags: condensed-matter, renormalization

Good evening. I am currently studying finite range corrections to Bogoliubov theory. Basically I assume that $V(q)=g_0+g_2q^2$, as a low energy expansion.
While computing some integrals in this area, i came across a divergent contribution stemming from the finite range coupling.
Namely i have 
$I=\frac{g_2}{(\frac{n_0g_2}{m}+\frac{\hbar^2}{4m^2})^{3/2}}\Gamma(1-\frac{D}{2})$, where D is the number of space dimensions of the system. Substituting for D=2 I find a divergent expression.
Now, when dealing with this kind of problems, it is customary to set $D=2-\epsilon$ and then take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ after some manipulation.
My issue is that i am not sure how to start. My idea would be to change $g_2 \to g_2 k^\epsilon$ and then consider $\tilde{g_2}(k,\epsilon)=\frac{g_2k^\epsilon}{(\frac{n_0g_2k^\epsilon}{m}+\frac{\hbar^2}{4m^2})^{3/2}}$ and then take the derivative w.r.t k and set $\epsilon$ to zero.
However i am very skeptical about this way of proceeding and i would gladly accept some input.